# VBA to iterate through table and move file from one folder to another

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am not very experienced with Excel VBA but I would like to iterate through a table and copy jpeg files from their current location to a new location as defined in a table array. I have tried a few pre-built subs without much luck. Can anyone assist with this?

[Table of source and destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvl4g.png)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFiles()
    Dim iRow As Integer         ' ROW COUNTER.
    Dim sSourcePath As String
    Dim sDestinationPath As String
    Dim sFileType As String
    
    Dim bContinue As Boolean
    
    bContinue = True
    iRow = 2
    
    ' THE SOURCE AND DESTINATION FOLDER WITH PATH.
    sSourcePath = "C:\books\"
    sDestinationPath = "C:\booksforclient\"
    
    sFileType = ".jpg"      ' TRY WITH OTHER FILE TYPES LIKE ".pdf".
   
    ' LOOP THROUGH COLUMN "B" TO PICK THE FILES.
    While bContinue
    
        If Len(Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Value) = 0 Then    ' DO NOTHING IF THE COLUMN IS BLANK.
            MsgBox "Process executed" ' DONE.
            bContinue = False
        Else
            ' CHECK IF FILES EXISTS.
            
            If Len(Dir(sSourcePath & Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Value & sFileType)) = 0 Then
                Range("C" & CStr(iRow)).Value = "Does Not Exists"
                Range("C" & CStr(iRow)).Font.Bold = True
            Else
                Range("C" & CStr(iRow)).Value = "On Hand"
                Range("C" & CStr(iRow)).Font.Bold = False
            
                If Trim(sDestinationPath) <> "" Then
                    Dim objFSO
                    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
                    
                    ' CHECK IF DESTINATION FOLDER EXISTS.
                    If objFSO.FolderExists(sDestinationPath) = False Then
                        MsgBox sDestinationPath & " Does Not Exists"
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                    
                    '*****
                    ' HERE I HAVE INCLUDED TWO DIFFERENT METHODS.
                    ' I HAVE COMMENTED THE SECOND METHOD. TO THE SEE THE RESULT OF THE 
                    ' SECOND METHOD, UNCOMMENT IT AND COMMENT THE FIRST METHOD.
                    
                    ' METHOD 1) - USING "CopyFile" METHOD TO COPY THE FILES.
                    objFSO.CopyFile Source:=sSourcePath & Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Value & _
                        sFileType, Destination:=sDestinationPath
                    
                    ' METHOD 2) - USING "MoveFile" METHOD TO PERMANENTLY MOVE THE FILES.
                    'objFSO.MoveFile Source:=sSourcePath & Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Value & _
                        sFileType, Destination:=sDestinationPath
                    '*****
                End If
            End If
        End If
       
       iRow = iRow + 1      ' INCREMENT ROW COUNTER.
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: "without much luck" doesn't tell us much about what's going wrong when you run your code

Comment: Does your screenshot of __Table of source and destination__ show exactly the data that this code will work with? I don't believe the `C:\books\C:\User\short\OneDrive\Desktop\FY21 Corps Photos\FY21 All Corps\Billy_Utecht.jpg.jpg` file will ever be found.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add one more column to your table, fill it with the formula

```
="move /-Y """ &[@CurrentLocation]&""" """&[@Desination]&""""
```

Select result and copy, open NotePad and paste. Save as BAT-file and run it.

*(Trust me, it will take much less time than writing and debugging a macro)*